# Minify JS embedded into .html file

Tags: javascript, html, minify, google-closure-compiler

I have an HTML file with javascript code embedded, here's a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type=”text/javascript”>
    // javascript code 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- some html -->
</body>
</html>
```

What's the easiest way to get the same file with all JS snippets *minified* inside it?

HTML file can be arbitrarily complex and have multiple script snippets.
For a number of reasons I don't need js split into separate .js files in the resulting html.

We use **closure compiler** and have **grunt** in the project.

Comment: Can you maintain your unimified javascript in a separate file and use grunt to minify the javascript and then replace a token in the html file with the minified javascript?

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh, yes, it would work, but how to debug these .html files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**
Use *html-minifier* which can do exactly what I need out of the box (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin, https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference)

So the grunt snippet would look like this:

```
htmlmin: {                                                              
    demo: {                                                         
        options: {                                                      
            removeComments: true,                                       
            collapseWhitespace: true,                                   
            minifyJS: true                                              
        },                                                              
        files: {                                                        
            'demo/demo.html'      
        }                                                               
    }                                                                   
}
```

**Option 2:**

Use https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize and https://github.com/PolymerLabs/crisper
 as @Chad Killingsworth suggested.

- **Crisper** enables extraction of embedded scripts into external files (.html and .js)
- Resulting .js files can be minified using any available minification tool
- **Vulcanize**, in turn, can combine all the files resulting from the previous steps into a single .html file

Looks like the most flexible approach. 
Besides, the original js could be stored in separate js files and then simply combined into single file using only **Vulcanize** without **Crisper**. Didn't have a chance to combine it into a grunt task that does what was requested though.

**Option 3:**

Grunt embed
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-embed,
https://github.com/callumlocke/resource-embedder)

Although it looks dead and does only a subset of things that Vulcanize can do, it provides awesome features like embedding depending on resource size and data attributes indicating what needs to be embedded

Grunt example: 
embed any external scripts and stylesheets under 5KB in size (the default threshold):

```
grunt.initConfig({
  embed: {
    some_target: {
      files: {
        'dest/output.html': 'src/input.html'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Html markup which would embed a particular resource, regardless of filesize

```
<script src="foo.js" data-embed></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css" data-embed>
```

To embed a particular resource only if it is below a certain size:

```
<script src="foo.js" data-embed="2000"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css" data-embed="5KB">
```

Answer (score 3):

The Polymer Project tools of [Vulcanize](https://github.com/Polymer/vulcanize) and [Crisper](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/crisper) can facilitate this.

Cripser will strip out JavaScript to it's own file, you can then minify it with the tool of your choice.

Vulcanize will take an external JavaScript file and inline it back.

Answer (score 1):

With **Webpack**, you can use `html-webpack-inline-source-plugin`. This is an extension plugin for the webpack plugin `html-webpack-plugin`. It allows you to embed javascript and css source inline.

Here is how it looks like in `webpack.config.js`:

```
const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: { index: 'src/index.js' },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html',
      minify: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeComments: true,
          minifyJS: true,
          minifyCSS: true
      },
      inlineSource: '.(js|css)$'
  })
  ...
```

Then all `.js` and `.css` will be inline in generated `index.html`.

**References:**

- [html webpack plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin)
- [Inline Source extension for the HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin)